# Convert XML file to String variable in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I'm looking to convert the contents of an XML file into a String variable in excel VBA so that I can search the file for a specific string.

However I don't know how to do the initial conversion from XML file to String variable. All I've been able to do so far is load the XML document, and from there I'm stuck.

```
Public Function DetermineSpecifiedChange(ByVal vstrInputGBOMPath As String, ByVal vstrInputPDPPath As String)


Dim strPDPString As String
Dim strGBOMString As String

Dim xmlGBOM As New DOMDocument60

Dim xmlPDP As New DOMDocument60

strPDPString = xmlPDP.Load(vstrInputPDPPath)

End Function
```

So far all this returns is "True", signifying that the file is being loaded.

How would I go about converting the XML file into a string?

Comment: You've got a structured XML file... Are you sure an unstructured text search is really what you want to do?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I'm not entirely sure at the moment.
What I'm trying to do is search for data in the xml document without knowing the node it's in beforehand, and this is the first thing I wanted to try. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Sure, look at the questions involving [VBA and XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+xpath). Using the `\\` selector will allow you to find a node anywhere in the tree.

Comment: ... I mean the \\ selector!  Damn escape characters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you ask:

```
Dim FSO As Object : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Dim strXml As String
strXml = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\myfile.xml").ReadAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that i'm currently using in one of my old application to convert file to string.

```
Private Function FileToText(fullFilePath as String) as string
Dim nFile           As Integer
Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
Dim sPostData       As String

nFile = FreeFile
Open fullFilePath For Binary Access Read As nFile
If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
End If
Close nFile FileToText = sPostData
FileToText = sPostData
```

This is a part of code from http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/